# Translating an ascii character from html in MySQL

Tags: html, mysql, ms-access, vba, ascii

I have a character that looks like this in the html: Â

So it looks like this: 9/15/13Â 9:09Â PMÂ ET

I bring the data into MySQL and it changes to a space, or just disappears.  So it looks like this: 9/15/13 9:09 PM ET

If I copy and paste that out of MySQL into MS Word it looks like it has degree symbols, like this: 9/15/13º9:09ºPMºET

In MS Access I want to just convert this to a date using CDate but it doesn't like it, so I want to use a function to remove it.  So I want to do something like instr([datefield],chr(250)) to identify the character and get rid of it.  But I can't find a Chr() code that locates it.  I tried everything that looks like Â or a degree symbol.

Comment: Ok I figured out that I can use a string function to chop off the "ET" at the end, and then the CDate() function is able to convert it to a datetime.  But still I would like to know how to get rid of the offending character properly, for future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an Access Immediate window session which demonstrates what I think you want with VBA.

```vb
? "9/15/13Â 9:09Â PMÂ ET"
9/15/13Â 9:09Â PMÂ ET
? Mid("9/15/13Â 9:09Â PMÂ ET", 8, 1)
Â
' use Asc() to get the character value
? Asc(Mid("9/15/13Â 9:09Â PMÂ ET", 8, 1))
 194 
' replace Â, Chr(194), with a space
? Replace("9/15/13Â 9:09Â PMÂ ET", Chr(194), " ")
9/15/13  9:09  PM  ET
' discard Â (replace it with zero-lenth string)
? Replace("9/15/13Â 9:09Â PMÂ ET", Chr(194), "")
9/15/13 9:09 PM ET
? Left(Replace("9/15/13Â 9:09Â PMÂ ET", Chr(194), ""), 15)
9/15/13 9:09 PM
' now make it a date
? CDate(Left(Replace("9/15/13Â 9:09Â PMÂ ET", Chr(194), ""), 15))
9/15/2013 9:09:00 PM
```